# Changing format for timestamp in Apache Directory Studio

Tags: apacheds

I have been trying to figure this out for a while and it's driving me crazy. I have a few attributes in my LDAP that are time/date stamps. Some of them show in z-time like `20170426221554Z` while others show in a more human readable form `Apr 26, 2017 4:15:54 PM MDT (20170426221554Z)`. I've looked through the settings, the help menu, and numerous places online and I cannot figure out how to change the format to something more readable. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Apache Directory Studio code you can't change the time format though the User Interface.

Attributes defined as Generalized Times (syntax OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.24) are displayed using default time formats for your locale. If the value is invalid then the raw string is displayed.

Extract from org.apache.directory.studio.valueeditors.time.GeneralizedTimeValueEditor:

```
public String getDisplayValue(IValue value) {
    String displayValue = super.getDisplayValue(value);
    if (!showRawValues()) {
        DateFormat targetFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.LONG);
        try {
            GeneralizedTime generalizedTime = new GeneralizedTime(displayValue);
            Date date = generalizedTime.getCalendar().getTime();
            displayValue = targetFormat.format(date) + " (" + displayValue + ")"; //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            // show the raw value in that case
        }
    }
    return displayValue;
}
```

If the Attribute is not a Generalised Time then it will display differently (i.e. a Directory String, syntax OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15, displays as a string)

You can check the syntax of an attribute in Apache Directory Studio (I'm using Version 2.0.0.v20161101-M12) by right clicking on the attribute and selecting properties then Attribute. The syntax information is about half way down.
[image: Attribute Properties]

Alternatively a search on base: ou-schema and filter on your attributes, such as:

```
(&
    (objectClass=metaAttributeType)
    (|
        (m-name=loginTime)
        (m-name=modifyTimestamp)
    )
)
```

will list the attributes.

If you own the LDAP schema then you can change the attribute syntax to use Generalized Time.

Comment: I'm not so sure. For example `loginTime` and `modifyTimestamp` both have the value of `20170509174757Z`. That is what is shown under "data" when I right click on the attribute, and select "properties". However, `modifyTimestamp` displays in the human readable form "May 9, 2017 11:47:57 AM MDT (20170509174757Z)".  Both show nothing for the syntax (or anything else for that matter) in the "attribute" section of the properties.

Comment: In my ldap setup there is no loginTime attribute, so I cant check it. A search with base: ou=schema, and filter: (&(objectClass=metaAttributeType)(|(m-name=loginTime)(m-name=modifyTimestamp))) and  should bring up the two attributes and then you can compare the definitions.

Comment: Here are screenshots of the properties:
http://imgur.com/a/vtmku
Still baffled why they are displaying differently.

Comment: I dont know why you cant see the syntax information. An alternative way to find the the attribute definitions is to run a search using the filter i have put in the answer above. This will only work if there is a visible ou=schema entry under the root of your LDAP database. I've been assuming you are using ApacheDS to access an Apache LDAP server, if it is a different server this could also be the problem.